# Can't get to fastboot. nor twrp nor OS - Xiaomi mi 5X/A1

Tags: twrp, xiaomi, mi-a1, android-one

I'm having a problem with my Xiaomi mi 5X and i wondered if someone on this forum could help me solve it.
As i said, i have a Xiaomi mi 5X but i changed its firmware and OS to the one of Mi A1 (Android One).
Today I was trying to install on my device the GCam app, with the tool Mi A1 GCam.
After I clicked the "Enable HAL3, EIS and install" the phone went dark. Now i can't boot into the OS, nor the twrp nor to the fastboot mode. When i try to do it i have to hold down the power button and corresponding volume key for several seconds and the Android One boot screen appears but just in a flash, and goes dark again. 
Can any of you help me, please?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using adb?

If you haven't got it already, download the SDK tools for windows from https://developer.android.com/studio/ under the "Command line tools only" section, and unzip it where you want.

Once you've done that, open a command prompt in the platform-tools folder within the SDK directory. The command

```
adp devices
```

will tell you that your device is connected. Then you can try

```
adp reboot recovery
```

If that doesn't work, install the universal adp driver and try again.